# LightFM: When do I make preserve_rows=True

Tags: python, recommendation-engine

In `LightFM`, the evaluation methods e.g. `precision_at_k` have a `preserve_rows` parameter with default value `False`. In what cases would I make it `True`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case some other bit of your code expected your score arrays to maintain their size. I wouldn't expect this to be common.

In most cases you just take a mean of the result.